# Check if an account is already registered in AccountManager

Tags: android, accountmanager

I'm trying to determine if the user already added the account, to prevent adding the same account multiple times on my app. I'm using my own account authenticator activity.
Here is my code:

```
public class AuthenticatorActivity extends AccountAuthenticatorActivity {



    private AccountManager mAccountManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setup_mail_dialog);
        mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext());


        findViewById(R.id.bSetupConfirm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAccount();

            }
        });

    }


    private void checkAccount() {
        mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext());
        String accountName = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSetupEmail)).getText().toString().trim();
        Account[] accounts = mAccountManager.getAccountsByType(getResources().getString(R.string.account_type));
        for(Account account : accounts) {
            if(account.name == accountName) {
                System.out.println("Account exists");
                return;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Account do not exists");
                return;
            }
        }

    }
```

However even if the account exists the app always show the "Account do not exists".

Comment: did you check `mAccountManager.getAccounts()` to see if the account is actually in there? If it is, is it of the correct type?

Comment: Yes, already tested and there are accounts.

Comment: One important note, you are going to check only the first one, the loop will stop after one compare as there is a return in both statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By references you must compare it with an equals.

The Solution:

```
 if(account.name.equals(accountName))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method

```
 private void isAccountExist() {
    AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
    Account[] accounts;
    if (accountManager != null) {
        accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (account.type.intern().equals("yourAccountType")) {
                // the account exist do your task
            }
        }
    }
}
```